# Get google+ reviews using Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-plus, google-places-api

I'm trying to debug something very weird.

I want to get reviews using Google Places API from this url:
[Henderson Nisan](https://plus.google.com/116549288957444910315/about?hl=ena658,1)

What I did?

- First I search for Google Place ID via this [URL](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) 
  And the result for the Place ID was: `ChIJoV7T0hjRyIAR24qv5IfRcWM`
- Than I fetch all information about Place with the next link:
  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=MY_API_KEY
- I'm getting those reviews: http://prntscr.com/8q7bsd

Problem is that those reviews which you can see on above printscreen are not corresponding to the reviews that are on the page of [Henderson Nisan](https://plus.google.com/116549288957444910315/about?hl=ena658,1)

Any kind of help will be acceptable. What I miss? Did I use wrong Place ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done what you've done:

1. searched for Henderson Nissan in https://developers.google.com/places/place-id , the returned place-id was `ChIJlfPkKh_RyIARWKYl-XpSyAQ` (not `ChIJoV7T0hjRyIAR24qv5IfRcWM` )
2. used this place-id to fetch results: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJlfPkKh_RyIARWKYl-XpSyAQ&key=mykey
3. the reviews there are related to the particular google+ page

it's not clear how you got the place-ID `ChIJoV7T0hjRyIAR24qv5IfRcWM`, but it's clear that the detailsRequest to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=MY_API_KEY uses a completely different place-ID: `ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4`  (for [Google-Sydney](https://plus.google.com/111337342022929067349/about) )

Comment: Thank you. I don't know. Still I'm getting wrong Place id. 
Which address did you used to find place id? Could you copy and paste it here.

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Henderson%20Nissan&key=addYourKeyHere (place_id of the first result for me is `ChIJlfPkKh_RyIARWKYl-XpSyAQ` )

Comment: This place API is just returning the 5 latest reviews but not all.